# NDSolve returns solution with single point domain

Tags: differential-equations

Thanks to helpful comments from Michael E2 and George2079, I was able to focus in on exactly the source of the issue. With some simplification, I can reduce the problem to:

```
NDSolve[{Derivative[1][y][t] == (-2 E^(1/5 y[t]) + 1)/(-600 E^(1/5 y[t]) +   
        20338 + (2/10) t ), y[101690] ==  0}, y, {t, 0, 101690}, 
        MaxSteps -> \[Infinity], WorkingPrecision -> 150]
```

It quickly throws:

```
NDSolve::ndcf: Repeated convergence test failure at t == <<185>>; unable to continue. >>
```

But this problem has an analytical solution:

```
y[t_] := 1/600 (2 t + C[1] + 3000 
         ProductLog[C[2], 
                   -((E^(-(t/1500) - C[1]/3000) (101690 + t))/3000)])/. 
         {C[1] -> 0, C[2] -> -1}
```

Which you can verify via:

```
In[1]:= N[y[101690]]
Out[1]= 0.

In[2]:= Simplify[y'[t] - 
                (-2 E^(1/5 y[t]) + 1)/(-600 E^(1/5 y[t]) + 20338 + (2/10) t)]
Out[2]= 0
```

This function is pretty well behaved.

I am hoping to understand the related issues with NDSolve, because I'm relying on that engine for more complex problems and this issue is a barrier to its application.

The documentation for the ndcf error says:

*If you see this message and the cause is not evident from the nature of the example, please send your example to Technical Support so that it can be investigated.*

Comment: I get a step-size-too-small error.  You have to increase the precision to around 100 to get effectively nonzero step sizes.  But they're still so small (~`10^-80` - `10^-30` for `PrecisionGoal -> 8`) that integration will never finish (effectively).

Comment: wrapping everything in `SetPrecision` is unintentionally also converting integers to reals. Now your equations are expressed in terms of variables such as `Cee[4.000000000000000000....]`.  Since now the symbols in the `vars` list (eg `Cee[4]`) do not appear in the equations you get a trivial solution.

Comment: You can fix that issue by instead doing `InitialConditions = {Cee[4][t0] == -270917. ... } /. x_Real :> SetPrecision[x, prec]`.   (With that fix I get an out of memory error though)

Answer (score 2):

The simplified system makes me forget why I suggested the issue concerned working precision. (The edit history shows the OP was much more complicated.)  Aside from the fact that @xzczd's answer shows a high `WorkingPrecision` is not needed, the convergence problem arises from `PrecisionGoal` and `AccuracyGoal` being automatically raised (to half `WorkingPrecision`).  That imposes a rather strict requirement with `WorkingPrecision -> 150`, which apparently `NDSolve` cannot satisfy.  There are two principal reasons for raising `WorkingPrecision` (WP):

- One cannot achieve the precision and accuracy goals at the current WP.  In such a case, raise WP but also manually set `PrecisionGoal` and `AccuracyGoal` to their current values (don't raise them).
- One wants to raise `PrecisionGoal` and `AccuracyGoal`.

The present case is the first one. We should set `PrecisionGoal -> 8` and `AccuracyGoal -> 8` (or other desired values).  With the high WP, `NDSolve` can get quite close to the singularity, making quite small steps.  I suggest setting `MaxSteps` to a finite value; `100000` takes a few seconds. You could set `MaxSteps -> 10000` (the default) to get the idea.

```
time = 0; steps = 0;
Dynamic@{time, steps}  (* monitor progress; it's educational *)

steps = 0;
{sol} = NDSolve[{Derivative[1][y][t] == (-2 E^(1/5 y[t]) + 1)/(-600 E^(1/5 y[t]) + 
       20338 + (2/10) t), y[101690] == 0}, y, {t, 0, 101690}, 
  MaxSteps -> 100000, WorkingPrecision -> 150, PrecisionGoal -> 8, 
  AccuracyGoal -> 8, StartingStepSize -> 0.001, 
  StepMonitor :> (time = t; steps++)]


ListLinePlot[N[y /. sol], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 1):

Without the 2 options, `NDSolve` manages to give the correct solution:

```
nsol = NDSolveValue[{Derivative[1][y][
     t] == (-2 E^(1/5 y[t]) + 1)/(-600 E^(1/5 y[t]) + 20338 + (2/10) t), y[101690] == 0},
   y, {t, 0, 101690}]
```

> NDSolveValue::ndsz

`NDSolve` spits out `ndsz` warning and stops at about `6883.23`, but this behavior is reasonable, because when `t < 6883.23` there's no **real** solution:

```
sol[t_] = 1/
     600 (2 t + C[1] + 
      3000 ProductLog[C[2], -((E^(-(t/1500) - C[1]/3000) (101690 + t))/3000)]) /. {C[
      1] -> 0, C[2] -> -1};

{{tL, tR}} = nsol["Domain"];
Plot[{Re@#, Im@#} &@sol@t // Evaluate, {t, 0, tR}, PlotRange -> All, 
  Epilog -> {Dashed, Line[{{tL, -10}, {tL, 20}}]}]~Show~
 Plot[nsol[t], {t, tL, tR}, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Dashed, Red}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]