# Monitor only every $n$-th step in NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, front-end, output, monitoring

I frequently use [`StepMonitor`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StepMonitor.html) to keep an eye on [`NDSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolve.html) while it's working. Usually it does the job just fine. Recently however, I've been working with sets of coupled ODEs that take several hundred iterations to solve. The business of oversight then gets rather tedious as you get hundreds of lines of intermediate values.

Is there a way to keep the output manageable by telling [`StepMonitor`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StepMonitor.html) to monitor only every $n$-th step?

---

**Simple Example**

Even an ODE as simple as

```
n = 1;
NDSolve[{y'[x] == y[x], y[0] == 1}, y, {x, 0, 5},
    StepMonitor :> Print[{n, x, y[x]}] n++] // Timing
```

results in 53 lines of intermediate results. What if I want, say, just 5 lines? Also, performing so many intermediate evaluations clearly introduces significant overhead. The above takes 0.002964 seconds to evaluate. By comparison, the same command without any monitoring,

```
NDSolve[{y'[x] == y[x], y[0] == 1}, y, {x, 0, 5}] // Timing
```

takes 0.00095 seconds, i.e. less than a third of the time.

Comment: I'm unclear as to why you'd want to monitor $n$-th steps. Recall that the built-in integrators are **adaptive**, so it is possible that, say, the 50th step, would only be a tiny fraction of the integration interval.

Comment: @J.M. Exactly! That's also part of what I want to learn from monitoring during evaluation. If `NDSolve` encounters a stiff system or a singularity, I'd know about sooner rather than later. Waiting for `NDSolve` to eventually fail due to vanishing step size wastes quite a bit of time, especially for more involved computations.

Comment: On my machine, calling `StepMonitor` in itself adds about `10^-5` sec. per step (plus whatever time it takes to compute the monitor expression). If the RHS of an ODE $d{\bf X}/dx = RHS({\bf X}, t)$ evaluates quickly like the OP's example, this is longer than the time to compute the step (which can also depend on the `Method`). This makes it appear in the OP's example as if `StepMonitor` slows `NDSolve` down by a ***factor*** of 3-4, whereas I'm suggesting it be viewed as ***adding*** a certain amount. (This is aside from the slight slowness and excessive output of `Print`.)

Comment: @MichaelE2 Good point. I may have jumped the gun there. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If only you need to reduce the number of printed lines, this [`Print`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Print.html)s once every 10 instances.

```
n = 1;
NDSolve[
  {y'[x] == y[x], y[0] == 1}
  , y
  , {x, 0, 5}
  , StepMonitor :> If[
    Mod[++n, 10] === 0
    , Echo[
     TemplateApply[StringTemplate["n:``, x:``, y:``", {n, x, y[x]}]]
     , "Monitor"]]
  ] // Timing
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

But the idea of filling the screen with updates seems sub-optimal. You could use a [`Dynamic`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dynamic.html) update of a single line. To reduce the overhead, this limits the update to once per second.

```
AbsoluteTiming[
 DynamicModule[{n = 1, status},
  Dynamic[Refresh[Row@status, UpdateInterval -> 1]];
  sol = NDSolve[{y'[x] == y[x], y[0] == 1}, y, {x, 0, 5}, 
    StepMonitor :> (status = {n += 1, x, y[x]})];]]
```

Obviously you could combine the two solutions.

**EDIT**

All that said, after a better answer by @george2079 it seems the correct tool to use is [`Monitor`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Monitor.html).

Comment: Is there any particular reason to prefer `Echo` over `Print`? It seems to increase computation time.

Comment: @Casimir, Mainly a new toy, it has labels so you can distinguish outputs from different sources, it can be used with non-string expressions. Probably  in this case may make sense to define an [EchoFunction](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EchoFunction.html).
`ef = Echo[TemplateApply[StringTemplate["n:``, x:``, y:``", #]], 
   "Monitor"] &`  and then `StepMonitor :> If[  Mod[++n, 10] === 0 , ef[{n, x, y[x]}]]`

Answer (score 5):

if you just want a status monitor you can do like this:

```
Monitor[NDSolve[{y'[x] == x, y[0] == 1}, y, {x, 0, 5}, 
  StepMonitor :> (p = x; ++n)], {n, p}]
```

this prints every step but wont clutter your screen.

There is inevitably an overhead, but typically in a real case where you care about monitoring results it will be small compared to the function eval.

this is useful sometimes too:

```
p = 0; ProgressIndicator[Dynamic[p], {0, 5}]
NDSolve[{y'[x] == f[x], y[0] == 1}, y, {x, 0, 5}, 
 StepMonitor :> (p = x)]
```

Note if `NDSolve` needs to do recursion then the -x- val wont accurately reflect progress however.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative suggestion, I usually use `Dynamic` to monitor progress. It seems to add minimal overhead (beyond the overhead of `StepMonitor`).  The use of `InputForm` lets one see small step sizes (how many digits are changed).

```
Dynamic@ InputForm@ foo
NDSolve[sys, y, {x, 0, 5}, StepMonitor :> (foo = x)]
```

---

Example from [NDSolve returns solution with single point domain](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/115389/ndsolve-returns-solution-with-single-point-domain/135968#135968):

Here `InputForm` is not really needed or helpful since arbitrary precision numbers are used. Their digits are printed out to their precision by default.

```
time = 0; steps = 0;
Dynamic@Column@{time, steps}  (* monitor progress; it's educational *)

steps = 0;
{sol} = NDSolve[{Derivative[1][y][t] == (-2 E^(1/5 y[t]) + 1)/(-600 E^(1/5 y[t]) + 
       20338 + (2/10) t), y[101690] == 0}, y, {t, 0, 101690}, 
  MaxSteps -> 100000, WorkingPrecision -> 150, PrecisionGoal -> 8, 
  AccuracyGoal -> 8, StartingStepSize -> 0.001, 
  StepMonitor :> (time = t; steps++)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Picking up on J.M.'s comment regarding adaptive step sizes, we can have `StepMonitor` only output a predetermined number of times while still keeping an eye on how many steps a given interval required:

```
runner = 1; counter = 0;
sol = NDSolve[{x'[t] == -Exp[x[t]], x[0] == 1}, x, {t, 0, 10}, 
  StepMonitor :> 
   counter++ If[t > runner, Print[{counter, t, x[t]}]; runner++]]
Plot[x[t] /. sol, {t, 0, 10}]
```

which gives

```
{50,1.03056,-0.335356}

{65,2.0474,-0.881814}

{74,3.01655,-1.21919}

{81,4.04807,-1.48522}

{87,5.19606,-1.71631}

{91,6.06848,-1.86196}

{95,7.22721,-2.0275}

{98,8.09626,-2.13584}

{101,9.25289,-2.26392}
```

[image]